# Chicken and egg email

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, activerecord

Here's the setup:

I have a system with many Accounts, each with many Users.  System superusers can broadcast a Message to all accounts.  A Messaging represents the joining between an account and a message.

Message after_create will generate a Messaging for each Account in the system.  Messaging after_create will deliver the message via email to each of that account's users.  The email will contain a link e.g. "click here to read the full message: http://example.com/messages/123"

Rails seems to perform this whole operation in memory and then commits to the database at the very last step.  Roughly:

```
Message
  after_create
    create_messagings
      ...
      Messaging
        after_create
          send_email
            "click here! example.com/messages/123"

            ...

            commit to database
```

What ends up happening is that emails begin getting delivered with the URL to the message, but that URL does not exist yet in the database until the last message is delivered.

I can't be the first one to come up against this...any ideas?

Currently this application is using Rails 3.0 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `Messaging.after_create` to `Messaging.after_commit`.

The [`after_commit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit) callback is called after a transaction has been committed, so this will ensure your `Message` & `Messaging` records exist in the database before you trigger the `send_email` method.